# Port Forwarding From Second Router

Tags: router, port-forwarding, smoothwall

I have the following setup at work, of which I'm impromptu in charge of:

Internet(Modem) <-> Smoothwall (firewall/dhcp/nat) <-> Servers/PCs

I need to be able to add a second broadband line in, preferable like this:

Internet_1(Modem) <-> Smoothwall (firewall/dhcp/nat) <-> Servers/PCs <-> Internet_2(Router)

I need to be able to port forward from a second broadband line using another router (Billion 7800N) to a windows 2008 server on the network.

What I can do:

- Create port forwarding rules on the Smoothwall machine
- Change any setting on Billion 7800

What I can't do:

- Change any network hardware/config on Servers/PC's/Smoothwall

What I have tried:

- Port forwarding to Smoothwall. From Smoothwall to server (local firewall off).

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you connect Internet_2 to Smoothwall?

Comment: If you can't change the firewall config, I would just stop until you can...

Comment: Unfortunately, there are all sorts of ports forwarding to IP's on Internet_1 that I have no control over.

The reason for the additional line is the increasing unreliability of the first line. It goes down briefly, and slows down for longer. Phone line company have not managed to fix. I need to slowly migrate things to second line, once tested, and get others to do the same, those that can change Ip's etc. I'm in a bind, struggling to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Try putting the second router between the modem and Smoothwall. Then port forward from the new router to Smoothwall.
2. Same as the first but instead of port forward, use the new router as a switch.
3. Local port forwarding on one of the servers via SSH or loopbacks.
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding
4. Create a bridge between the two routers.

Hope this either helps or creates a spark!

Comment: Those may be beyond the limits of what I am allowed to risk changing, but I will certainly look into those options, thanks :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity and for everyone else's benefit, could you please tell me what worked?